# How to store a reference to the "active element" using AngularJS and AngularFire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a simple note app that shows a list of notes and the active, selected note in a textarea. I want to be able to select a note in the list and edit it.

In my controller I have an "active" variable that points to an item in the list of notes. Using just AngularJS this works fine. If I add AngularFire the active element is no longer connected whenever I change the contents in the textarea. Is it a bad idea to store this active reference?

Here is the relevant part of the controller:

```
var notesApp = angular.module('notesApp', ['firebase']);
function NotesCtrl($scope, angularFire) {
    var fireBaseUrl = new Firebase('https://mynotesapp.firebaseio.com/notes');
    $scope.notes = [];
    $scope.select = function (note) {
        $scope.active = note;
    };
    angularFire(fireBaseUrl, $scope, 'notes').then(function () {
        $scope.active = $scope.notes[0];
    });
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="note in notes" ng-class="{active: note == active}">
    <a href="#" ng-click="select(note)">{{ note.title }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<textarea ng-model="active.body"></textarea>
```

A complete example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4zsMH/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you are copying the selected note to $scope.active ..firebase binding is lost. I have modified your code a little, and it works now.

http://jsfiddle.net/MXUxZ/

View

```
<div ng-app="notesApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="NotesCtrl">
        <div class="row">
             <h1>Notes</h1>

            <ul class="note-list col-xs-3 nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li ng-repeat="note in notes" ng-class="{active: selectedIndex == $index}"><a href="#" ng-click="select($index)">{{ note.title }}</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" ng-click="addNote()">+ Add Note</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="note-detail col-xs-9">
                <textarea rows="20" style="width:100%" ng-model="notes[selectedIndex].body"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var notesApp = angular.module('notesApp', ['firebase']);

function NotesCtrl($scope, angularFire) {
    var fireBaseUrl = new Firebase('https://notes6754.firebaseio.com/notes');
    $scope.notes = [];
    $scope.select = function (note) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = note;
    };
    $scope.addNote = function () {
        var title = prompt('Note Title');
        if (title) {
            var note = {
                title: title,
                body: 'Replace me'
            };
            $scope.notes.push(note);
            $scope.active = note;
        }
    };
    angularFire(fireBaseUrl, $scope, 'notes').then(function () {
        $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: So your suggestion is to keep the index of the element as the reference? Is this idiomatic use of Angular?

Comment: Not really idiomatic use, but the key is that firebase will not work with reference object. If it's only angular, I shall use your present approach. But since you are binding the model with firebase model, I think this is one of the way of achieving it.